# How to restrict shipping address per product?

Tags: product, magento-1.9, shipping

I want to restrict shipping per product. Is there maybe a way/module that makes the following possible:

- Create an attribute called for example: restrictedcountries
- Multiple choice box on product edit page so we can choose where the product CANNOT be shipped to.
- Note on front-end where it says 'This product cannot be shipped to your country'
- Extra possibility: to import/export CSV file with 2 rows: SKU and restrictedcountries
  For example:

  **SKU,restrictedcountries**

  115,MY;NA;PG;VC;CH;AE;RS

  253,MD;MP;RU;LK;TN;WF
- GeoIP would also be handy, so a customer can see at the product page if this product can't be shipped to the customer's country.

Someone who know's how to do this would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I would implement a multi select attribute to add the allowed/disallowed countries, then you can ask in the frontend for the attribute wherever you want (as long as you know the shipping address).

And you can check the attribute during checkout to make sure, it is not checked out with this condition.

The third cool thing is, that you can use import/export to import these countries!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of available at the magento connect [shipping restriction](http://amasty.com/shipping-restrictions.html) module:

It allows to restrict by product attributes, countries and other order details:[image: shipping restriction example]

This is a paid module, made by Amasty.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, [Zones Manager](http://innoexts.com/zone-release-1000/), it enables to set up geographic zones and restrict a product per zone: